# Identifying images not belonging to the classes the CNN is trained with

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

lets say that I have an app with CNN trained to predict cats and dogs and a user inputs an image of an apple and my CNN predicts the apple as either a cat or dog. How to I get my app to say that the user has input a wrong image and not make and predictions ?

Would love to know how you guys deal with similar situations.

Comment: you can filter by probability: if probability (softmax output) of cats exceed 90% - it is cat, if prob of dogs exceed 90% - it is dog, else - wrong image

Answer (score 1):

*Well, there could be lots of ways to go for it, however, here's some simple approaches.*

#### Approach: 1

If you have 2 classes in your dataset, then simply **add a third class** which is the "`unknown class`" and **represents some random data**, which means you can add all the garbage (outliers) you want in that class like photos of apple, flower, birds, etc (where to get these images? simply download and concatenate another dataset like cifar-10, etc.). Then you can **train your network on this data**, the network will predict the third class "`unknown class`" when it is neither a dog nor a cat.

#### Approach: 2

***However***, a better approach (in my opinion) would be to **have 2 neurons in the output layer with a sigmoid activation**, one represents the probability of being a cat and the other is the probability of being a dog. So after training, when you feed an image of a dog, you may get this kinda value in your output layer `[0.9, 0.07]` (90% probability of dog and 7% of the cat). So intuitively, when you'll feed a random image (like the image of an apple), the output layer may produce the following output `[0.3, 0.27]`, so the network seems to be not confident whether it's a cat or a dog. Now it's pretty easy for you to set a threshold, say 60%, so only when the model predicts cat or dog with more than 60% probability you send the output/prediction to the user, otherwise you send "unknown class" as output.